# Using Recursion to get the sum sqrt of a list

Tags: haskell

Ive been trying to create a recursive function that takes a list of integers and gets the sum of the square root.
i've come from c# and im pretty new to haskell. I feel as though ive hit a comprehension block

i was having problems with types so i tried making an integer sqrt to help myself out, but ended up confusing myself more..

```
isqrt :: Integer -> Integer
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

sumsquares :: Int a => [a] -> a
sumsquares f [] = "List is Empty"
sumsquares f (x:xs) | sum . isqrt  x | x <- xs
```

ive only done a little recursion and i can't find anywhere that really explains it in a way i understand

Comment: You _do_ realise that this is one of those situations not really suited to recursion, don't you? :-)

Answer (score 2):

### How your code is uncompilable

```
sumsquares :: Int a => [a] -> a
```

The type signature is weird. `Int` is a type but you are using with the class syntax. What you really meant ("a list of integers") was:

```
[Integer] -> Integer
```

You are also taking as an argument an `f` that simply isn't there. This makes me think that you thought `Int a =>` was an argument. It's not. Anything in the form `X a =>` is a type class constraint that does not contribute to the arity of the function.

Then we have:

```
sumsquares f [] = "List is Empty"
```

This is unreasonable and incorrect. Generally speaking one would expect that the sum of an empty list is `0` or `mempty` (that's for a more complicated topic). `"List is Empty"` is a `String` (unless `OverloadedString` is in place), so that line wouldn't even compile.

Finally:

```
sumsquares f (x:xs) | sum . isqrt  x | x <- xs
```

I don't know what you were trying to do here, but `|` is used for conditionals. For example:

```
sumSquares :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumSquares x
    | null x    = 0
    | otherwise = (isqrt . head $ x) + tail x
```

### Solution with explicit recursion

That would be like this:

```
sumSquares :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumSquares []       = 0
sumSquares (x:xs)   = isqrt x + sumSquares xs
```

### Solution with `map`

Using `map`, it's simply:

```
sumSquares :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumSquares = sum . map isqrt
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `isqrt` looks good.

The type signature on `sumsquares` is wrong; `Int` isn't a class, it's a type. So you probably wanted to write `[Int] -> Int`. Note also that `Integer` and `Int` aren't the same. (`Int` is typically 32-bit, whereas `Integer` can hold *thousands* of bits.)

Not sure what the `f` parameter is supposed to be for. (It's also not mentioned in your type signature, so that won't work.)

You can't have one equation return a string (`"List is Empty"`) and another one return a number. They have to both return numbers. I would suggest that no numbers add up to zero.

You *probably* wanted to write something like

```
sumsquares :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumsquares [] = 0
sumsquares (x:xs) = isqrt x + sumsquares xs
```

Do you see why that works? The `sumsquare` of an empty list is just zero, otherwise apply `isqrt` to the first element, recursively sum the remaining elements, and add the two results.